# How to better write linq selectmanys in terms of perfomance - nest or chain?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

For example, I have some classes:

```csharp
class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public List<int> Ints { get; set; }
}
```

then, when I want to get collection of all ints from some `Foo` collection (either `IQueryable` from ef core or `IEnumerable`), I can write:

1. Nested

```csharp
foos.SelectMany(x => x.Bars.SelectMany(y => y.Ints))
```

2. Chained

```cs
foos.SelectMany(x => x.Bars).SelectMany(x => x.Ints)
```

What approach is faster for queries from db and actions on `IEnumerable`? And why?

Comment: why not just measure it? How should we know, when we have no clue about your DBMS for instance? But even that will not give an answer, as it highly depends on the amount of data you transfer for instance and many different factors. In short: just **measure** and see if there's any difference at all.

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) - Eric Lippert.

Comment: I'd rather suggest to see if your DB even understands these queries prouced by EF, before bothering about nanoseconds.

Comment: I couldn't resist, so I did some dead simple testing. I didn't know your possible distribution, so I just do random from 10 - 100 foos containing 10 - 100 Bars containing 10 - 100 ints and counting the result. Multiple runs resulted in Nested and Chained swapping places as to which is faster, and I would expect (for `IEnumerable`) that the results are roughly equal as they will execute about the same amount of similar code.

Comment: `List<int>` isn't a valid entity property. The question is about EF Core?